# Integer increment inside firebase call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My increment of an integer is behaving weird. On my last database call it's being set to 2,2,2 instead of going from 0,1,2. Anyone see the problem?

```
let chats = firebase.database().ref(`/userProfile/${this.userAuth.uid}/messages/`);
let profiles = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile');
chats.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let i = -1;
  this.messagesList = [];

  for (let key in snapshot.val()) {
    i++;

    chats.child(key).limitToLast(1).on('value', (data) => {
      this.messagesList[i] = data.val();
      for (let message in this.messagesList[i]) {
        this.messagesList[i].conversation_key = message;
      }
      console.log(i); // RETURNS 0,1,2
    });

    console.log(i); // RETURNS 0,1,2

    profiles.child(key).on('value', (data) => {
      console.log(i); // RETURNS 2,2,2
      this.messagesList[i].firstname = data.val().firstname;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a asynchronous problem. By the time `profiles` are fetched from the database and the callback function is being executed the `for`-loop has already completed.

Try and move the `chats.child()` and `i++` statements inside the callback function of the `profile.child()` statement.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other way around. Move chats.child and i++ to the callback of profiles.child. The problem is still as stated, the for-loop completes before profile.child. You need to synchronize the increment to that of profiles.child.